# Add a custom text to GNOME panel

Tags: 12.10, gnome-panel, gnome-classic, applet, extension

I want to add some text to the GNOME panel in GNOME Classic.

I got a suggestion from this [blog](http://oesediez.blogspot.com/2008/10/add-text-message-to-gnome-panel.html) but it dates back to 2008 and doesn't seem applicable now.

In Ubuntu 12.10 and GNOME classic, the option of `/apps/panel/applets/clock_screen0/prefs/custom_format` in `gconf-editor` is missing.

So is there any way I can add custom text to the clock in GNOME classic?

Also is there any other applet/extension available which allows us to add a text to the GNOME panel?

Comment: Those instructions no longer work in 12.10 as it uses Gnome 3.5/3.6. You can change how the clock displays the time from the Gnome Control Center>Clock.

Comment: But the clock stetting under Gnome Control center does not allows me to add some custom text.

Comment: No that only changes the format of the clock as per your question: *So is there any way I can change the format of the clock in gnome classic?*. You can try with Gnome Shell, use extensions to make it look like the Classic session and find one extension that changes the Clock though that seems too much for just the text in the clock.

Comment: That blog linked to a Ubuntu Forums thread which in turn linked to an external image that doesn't seem available anymore. So what exactly do you want? I have a digital clock set up like this: `Thu 21 Feb 03 : 41`. Is it correct that you want to add some text before `Thu` or after `41` (in this example)?

Comment: @vasa1 There is custom text next to the clock it says tango,  that's what the OP wants though I'm most certain that it can't be done.

Comment: I can do that in Lubuntu with the **default** digital clock applet. The problem is that I don't know anything about that applet, whether it's specific to Lubuntu, and if it isn't where someone using GNOME can pick it up from. I just added "anything here" ahead of `Thu` without a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple Gnome extension may be worth to try. (I'm not sure about naming, in Ubuntu 14.04: Gnome classic uses same Gnome shell extensions, Where old classic renamed to Gnome Fallback)

---

### Gnome Classic & Mate

1. Download [panel-applet-generator](https://github.com/eighthave/panel-applet-generator)
2. Generate a new applet:

   ```
   python panel-applet-generator.py -n mylabel -d "my custom label"
   ```
3. Modify `mylabelApplet.py`

   ```
   try:
       from gi.repository import Gtk
   except: # Can't use ImportError, as gi.repository isn't quite that nice...
       import gtk as Gtk

   def applet_factory(applet, iid, data = None):
       button = Gtk.Button("It works!")
       label = Gtk.Label("It works!")
       applet.add(label)
       applet.show_all()
       return True
   ```

   I added `label = Gtk.Label("It works!")` and modified `applet.add(label)` (It was `applet.add(button)`)
4. Compress mylabel folder as tar.gz then rename it to `mylabel_1.0.orig.tar.gz`
5. Build Debian package

   ```
   cd mylabel/
   debuild -us -uc
   ```
6. Install package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i ../*.deb
   ```
7. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> on panel, then add to panel
8. Look for mylabel applet, then add

[image]

References:

- [Making panel applets for Gnome 2 and 3](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2012/02/29/making-panel-applets-for-gnome-2-and-3)
- [IntroDebianPackaging](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging)

Note:

- If for any reason unable to install, It is possible to do it manually:

  ```
  sudo cp org.gnome.applets.mylabel.panel-applet /usr/share/gnome-panel/4.0/applets/
  sudo cp org.gnome.panel.applet.mylabel.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
  sudo cp *.py /usr/lib/gnome-applets/
  ```

  32bit system:

  ```
  sudo cp mylabel.server /usr/lib/bonobo/servers/
  ```

  64bit system:

  ```
  sudo cp mylabel.server /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bonobo/servers/
  ```

---

### Gnome Shell

I have tested it with Gnome 3.10:

1. Install Gnome tweak tool

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Create new extension:

   ```
   gnome-shell-extension-tool --create-extension
   ```
3. Enter requested info: name `My Label`, description `Extension shows my custom text`, uuid `mylabel@yourname` or leave as default `mylabel@hostname`

   Extension created in `/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/mylabel@hostname`
4. `extension.js` is auto opened. Replace Icon with your custom label. As below:

   ```
   function init() {
       button = new St.Bin({ style_class: 'panel-button',
                             reactive: true,
                             can_focus: true,
                             x_fill: true,
                             y_fill: false,
                             track_hover: true });
       let icon = new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'system-run-symbolic',
                                style_class: 'system-status-icon' });

       let label = new St.Label({ text: "Hello, world!" });
       button.set_child(label);
       button.connect('button-press-event', _showHello);
   }
   ```

   I added `let label = new St.Label({ text: "Hello, world!" });` and modified `'button.set_child(label);` (It was `button.set_child(icon);`)
5. Save, Restart Gnome-Shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `r` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Launch Gnome Tweak Tool → Extensions → Enable `My Label` extension.
7. Restart Gnome-Shell again.

   [image]

References:

- [Step by step tutorial to create extensions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial)
- [St Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/st/stable/)
- [Documentation for writing Gnome shell extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107743/documentation-for-writing-gnome-shell-extensions)
- [Making GNOME Shell Extensions](http://codeisland.org/2013/making-gnome-shell-extensions/)

Comment: Great Solution!! I have been looking for something like this. But unfortunately I could not install it in my Gnome Classic. So I was wondering if you have any solution for creating such "Hello World" applet in Gnome Classic.

Comment: I would like ask you to add your Gnome Classic version to the question, just to confirm. I may give it a try later. I couldn't give you any promise.

Comment: Great work, and effort. Thanks. Really a life saver when I am compulsively using the internet.

Comment: There is interest in this for version 18.04 but reportedly doesn't work here: [Is there a way to show external IP in top bar using GNOME 3.28.2 in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1198054/307523)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, Gnome Shell was changing faster without weak backward compatibility that I couldn't keep up. It seems that question already got an answer that solution has clear source here https://github.com/rostegg/public-ip-gnome-extension. Whenever I have time I may update it, I put the link here if anyone may need for time being.

Comment: @user.dz If I had a dollar for every Gnome Shell & Wayland complaint I'd be a millionaire. I've used Unity / Xorg throughout 14.04, 16.04, 18.04 and 19.04 so all my time consuming written works still work. I'll probably do the same in 20.04 because I'm not a big fan of reinventing the wheel. I do hope Canonical does take new developments in Gnome world and port them to Unity though...

Answer (score 0):

on 20.04, there is this working extension that can use dbus to set the text:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2826/generic-monitor/?c=78316

and here the readme:
http://indefero.soutade.fr/p/genericmonitor/source/tree/master/README.md
and this is what I use (a 1min loop), as I can't find another way to cfg datetime the way I want:

```
while true;do
  strDate="`date +"%A, %Hh%Mm - %d %B (%m/%Y)"`";
  gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /com/soutade/GenericMonitor --method com.soutade.GenericMonitor.notify \
    '{"group":"new","items":[{"name":"first","text":"'"$strDate"'","style":"color:white"}]}'
  sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's (still) looking for it, here's a much easier solution. A gnome extension called One Thing (named after a similar app for Mac)

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5072/one-thing/