# Is there a way to show external IP in top bar using GNOME 3.28.2 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, ip, top-bar

Using some answers I found here: [Add a custom text to GNOME panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259174/add-a-custom-text-to-gnome-panel)

I have tried making my own applet but I have not succeeded.

Does someone know of an application that works in Ubuntu 18.04?

There used to be an application for 17.10 that's called indicator-ip by bovender. But it doesn't work for 18.04

Comment: To programmatically retrieve your IP address using `bash`, I recommend `curl ifconfig.co`. I don't know how that will go to your GNOME panel, though.

Comment: As already mentioned by OP this would be duplicate but doesn't work in 18.04: [Is it possible to show ip address on top bar near the time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024866/is-it-possible-to-show-ip-address-on-top-bar-near-the-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [Indicator System Monitor](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor) for years on Ubuntu 16.04:

[image: indicator system monitor.gif]

I haven't used it with Gnome but the link above states:

> ### Indicator-SysMonitor - v0.8.2
>
> An Application Indicator showing cpu temperature, memory, network
> speed, cpu usage, public IP address and internet connection status .
>
> Works with Unity, Xubuntu, Gnome-Shell + app-indicator extension
> together with any other desktop environments that support
> AppIndicators.
>
> Also works with the Budgie-Desktop
>
> Offers the possibility to run your own command and display its output.

Even though it already offers an option to display Public IP you can still write your own bash script which refreshes every x seconds with custom display information, in my case above a spinning pizza with time remaining in washing machine wash cycle (so you are told when to add fabric softener for rinse cycle).

Indicator System Monitor is maintained by FossFreedom who is a regular visitor to Ask Ubuntu website.

Comment: Nice one. Gonna try that one later today

Comment: You don't have a washing machine where you can add fabric softener at the start of the program?  **:0**  Have +1 instead then!  **;-) >:-)**

Comment: @Fabby In an apartment building. The best part of the program is when dryer ends, so I never leave clothes in overnight like in the old days before they invented computers :)

Comment: @Rinzwind If you are interested in the spinning pizza for showing a bash job is in progress see: [Can BASH display in systray as application indicator?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882419/can-bash-display-in-systray-as-application-indicator/882420#882420) **WARNING:** Self-answered question :)